# Quadruple-precision (128 bit) arithmetic

Tags: machine-precision, arbitrary-precision

Is it possible to force Mathematica to perform computations with hardware supported quadruple-precision? The following test suggest, that all of the computations with fixed precision, different than `$MachinePrecision=15.9546`, are performed via the same arbitrary precision algorithm. Am I right?
Is it possible to speed up 34 digit accurate computations?

```
num = RandomInteger[{1, 100}, 5 10^5];
First@AbsoluteTiming[
  Sin[N[num]];
]
(* ==> 0.273485 *)

{#, First@AbsoluteTiming[
 Sin[N[num, #]];]} & /@ Range[32, 36]

(* ==>
{{32, 10.224581}, {33, 9.942714}, {34, 10.043138},
{35, 9.856203}, {36, 9.929918}}
*)
```

Comment: Not possible to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: I'm curious, which hardware platform are you using?

Comment: @sebhofer I'm also curious about that. According to [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadruple-precision_floating-point_format#Hardware_support), 128-bit floats are not natively supported on the x86 architecture.  Maybe he meant [80-bit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_precision) precision?  This could be the reason why Mma doesn't support quadruple precision.  A little googling shows that on Intel processors 128-bit precision is implemented in software (when certain compilers support it).

Answer (score 18):

As the comments indicate, there is no completely hardware-based solution - but that doesn't mean you can't do some tweaking. The trick is always: **stick with machine precision as long as you can, then switch to arbitrary precision only to refine your results**.

Instead of making up an example (which is hard because Mathematica implements the above principle automatically in many cases, as observed in the comment - which caused me to **delete an earlier example**), I'll address the problem given in your question some more. It can also be sped up considerably by deferring the use of arbitrary precision (in this case the application of `N[...,36]` etc.) to the end:

```
{#, First@AbsoluteTiming[N[Sin[num], #];]} & /@ Range[32, 36]
```

> `{{32, 0.931845}, {33, 0.871302}, {34, 0.858584}, {35, 0.852693}, {36, 
>     0.849243}}`

All I did was to move the `N` outside the `Sin`, and the timing is an order of magnitude faster.